# Does polynomial regression work when X is multidimensional?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm learning about linear regression, in particular how to derive the parameters using MLE with the formula given by [image]

However, I wanted to ask whether this formula works when X is multidimensional or does it work when `X` is just a `N` by `1` vector. Because when I implement this formula using `sklearn.linear_models.LinearRegresion` I get completely different answers. For example I have the following code, outputting different values:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
boston_dataset = datasets.load_boston()
features = ['TAX', 'LSTAT']
X = df[features]
Y = boston_dataset.target
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X)
print(f"Gradient: {model.coef_}")
print(f"y-intercept: {model.intercept_}")
```

outputs

```
Gradient: [-0.0052125  -0.88312682]
y-intercept: 35.83500136724426
```

However:

```
Phi = np.hstack((np.ones((len(X), 1)), X))
theta = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(Phi.T, Phi)), Phi.T), np.expand_dims(boston_dataset.target, 1))
theta
```

Outputs the following:

```
array([[ 3.58350014e+01],
       [-5.21249838e-03],
       [-8.83126823e-01]])
```

As you can see I get completely different answers for both the gradients and the y-intercept. Could somebody help me with my implementation or show me an article implementing this formula to find the parameters using the MLE (and not `sklearn`)